# SQL code performance

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL query which takes a lot of time to execute.

It goes like this

```
select 
    columns
from 
    tab1
where
    tab1.id in (select col from tab2 where conditions) --32000 rows
    or 
    tab1.id in  (select col from tab3 where conditions) ---14000 rows
    or
    tab1.id in  (select col from tab4 where conditions) --6000 rows
```

Is there any way I can increase the performance here?

I've tried using `EXISTS()` too but that did not help.

Comment: Did you try to do what you want to do using JOINs?

Comment: explain "conditions". Why not join?

Comment: What is the query plan?  What indexes are available?  What does "a lot of time to execute" mean?  How expensive are each of your three `IN` clause statements on their own?

Comment: It takes more than 8mins and its still processing in toad. I've  ran an explain plan on each of the in class statements  tab2(cost 24764),tab3(cost 20945),tab4(cost 10254)---I have very little knowledge of the explain plan

Comment: Run `explain plan for select ...` and then `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);` and post the results here so everyone can see the explain plan in a readable format.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle should be pretty good with optimizing queries that have `in` with a subquery.  Your best bet is adding indexes.  However, your query is not detailed enough to suggest particular indexes.  You need to be explicit about the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

option1:

```
select 
    columns
from 
    tab1
where
    tab1.id in (select col from tab2 where conditions  --32000 rows
                 union all
                select col from tab3 where conditions ---14000 rows
                 union all    
                select col from tab4 where conditions --6000 rows
               );
```

option2:

```
select 
    columns
from 
    tab1
inner join (select distinct col
             from (select col from tab2 where conditions  --32000 rows
                 union all
                select col from tab3 where conditions ---14000 rows
                 union all    
                select col from tab4 where conditions --6000 rows
               )
            ) x
   on tab1.id = x.col;
```

option3:

```
select 
    columns
from 
    tab1
where
    exists (select col from tab2 where conditions  --??? rows
             where col = tab1.id
                 union all
                select col from tab3 where conditions ---??? rows
                 where col = tab1.id
                 union all    
                select col from tab4 where conditions --??? rows
                 where col = tab1.id
               );
```